# In Cesium, billboards are putting holes in polygon entities

Tags: javascript, gis, cesiumjs

I am needing billboard entities to sometimes sit on top of polygon entities.  The problem I am seeing is that the billboard entities are creating holes in the polygons.  Almost as if there's some phantom space buffer around the icon.

I have a little sandcastle example showing this behavior here:

http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Apps/Sandcastle/?src=Hello%20World.html&label=Showcases&gist=12a366a687f3c490e517b9a6af15ded9

Notice how as you move the globe, the hole also changes.  I imagine this behavior could come from the way these entities are being rendered.. but is there a way through the entity or billboardGraphics API to avoid this issue?  Or does this issue stem from entity z-fighting?

Comment: It looks like this may have been fixed in Cesium 1.23.  At the very least, your example no longer shows the problem as of that version (and does show it with prior versions).  Is this fixed for you?